# Overlay fadeOut then fadeIn does not display the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a google map as some sort of sidebar and an overlay which is black with `opacity: 0.5;` to disable map interaction when the content section is open. When the content section is closed the map overlay fades out and gets `display: none;` css attribute to enable map interaction.

I use the jQuery `fadeOut` and `fadeTo` methods.

Fading the overlay out works as expected. It will animate the overlay to `opacity: 0;` after which it will put `display: none;` so the user can interact with the map.

But when a user closes the map again the overlay should reappear with `opacity: 0.5;` and `display: block;` The properties are there but the overlay is not visible. When you hover elements in the chrome inspector or change the width with 1px for example the overlay will jump into appearance. It feels like a browser bug/glitch.

Demo version available at: http://qact.us/bijverdienen/

Any help/advice in how/why this is happening is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Safari has the same problem so webkit specific i guess.

Comment: Can you put a fiddle together? - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I tried to put a fiddle together but i am not able to reproduce, it must have something to do with the other elements on the page. Test version live on: http://qact.us/bijverdienen/